# Geometric Vectors - Hard Question

Tags: vectors

I have a question. I solved most of it, but I need help with the last part.

In a triangle ABC the height to AB is CD.

$\vec{CA}=\underline{u},\ \vec{CB}=\underline{v}, \ \vec{AD}=t\vec{AB},\  cos(\angle ACB )=\frac{3}{4}, \ |\vec{CA}|=1, \ |\vec{CB}|=2$

1. find $t$.
2. The point E is on the segment BC such that $\frac{CE}{BE}=\frac{3}{5}$ and $\vec{CD}=\underline{h}$

2.1 express $\underline{h}$ using $\underline{u}, \ \underline{v}$

2.2 express $\underline{v}$ using $\underline{h}, \ \underline{u}$

2.3 express $\vec{AE}$ using $\underline{h}, \ \underline{u}$ (do not use 2.1 and 2.2)

My answer

1. $t=-\frac{1}{4}$

this is how it looks:

[image]

2.1 $\underline{h}=\frac{5}{4} \underline{u} - \frac{1}{4} \underline{v} $

2.2 I used the equation on 2.1 and got:

$\underline{v}=5\underline{u}-4\underline{h}$

2.3 I have no idea how to solve without using 2.1 and 2.2 but I tried to solve it with 2.1 and 2.2 and got:

$\vec{AE}=\frac{7}{8} \underline{u} - \frac{3}{2} \underline{h}$

I think I'm suppose to use Geometry or Trigonometry (maybe the Law of cosines on triangle AEC) but I have no Idea, this is how it looks:

[image]

I manage to find that $|\vec{AE}|=\frac{\sqrt{7}}{4}$ but I have no idea how it can help me.

If anyone know how to do it without using 2.1 and 2.2 I will be grateful!